# How to calculate BW ofdm?

Tags: sampling, ofdm, bandwidth

HI I have these specification for an OFDM program I was wondering, what is the bandwidth and the sampling frequency? I'm not a student of Digital signal processing, hence I am so confused.

```
ymax=100;
nIFFT = 2048;
nCyclic = nIFFT/4;
pilot_distance = 16;
pilot_amplitude = 2;
offset = nIFFT*3;
% total number of complex samples in the timedomain
nTotal = (nIFFT+nCyclic)*ymax+offset;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to deduce the sampling rate from this information. The sampling rate could be anything, since FFT is sampling rate agnostic. Sampling rate is pretty much independent of all other parameters which scale directly with it.

Concerning the bandwidth, it's not clear either. You're specifying pilot distance, but we don't know what the units are and we never see how those variables get used. Is there more to the code you're studying?

---

Looked at your full code, and the sampling rate is 8 kHz, since that's what frequency is used in the `wavwrite` command. Will have to get back to bandwidth.

Comment: Hi, yes there is http://pastethis.in/?paste=1590
pwd = modem.
hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the sampling frequency.But Sorry, I am still unclear about the bandwidth.

Comment: Assuming that all subcarriers are modulated, the bandwidth is approximately equal to the sampling frequency.